# bot framework disable user input box

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using the below code so that the user must choose Yes/No for an answer

```
PromptDialog.Confirm(context,confirmOption,"Are you sure?");
```

The confirmOption part, simply gives a response if Yes or No is pressed.
Is it possible to disable the user input box in order to block the user from entering irrelevant text and enable it after choosing Yes/No?

Comment: On which channel?

Comment: This is not possible natively in the bot framework.  I think @Nicolas R has a custom solution for webchat though and that is why he is asking which channel :)

Comment: Yes Jason, that's it ;-) or in fact I don't have it but it must be possible by editing the webchat

Comment: @NicolasR Well at the moment for skype and facebook messennger. I was thinking that I am asking the user to select a specific option so there must be a way to block him from writing irrelevant words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in channels like Skype of Facebook Messenger, as you do not have access to the implementation.

But if you are using Prompts correctly the input of the user can be automatically compared to the options and validated even if it is not exactly the same value. You can also enable the fact that the user can say "the first one" or an equivalent and detect that as the 1st option.

In the case of a PromptConfirm, it will try to match several values, depending of the Locale. For example in English (see Resources file [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Resource/Resources.en.resx#L92)):

- For No, default values are: "No;n;nope;2
- For Yes: "Yes;y;sure;ok;yep;1"